# Variable-length form using Django and JS

Tags: javascript, django

I want to create a form with a number of textareas. The user will, ideally, be able to press a button on the page to add another textarea to the form. I've gotten this simple part working with a tiny bit of JS, but I'm not sure what to do about submitting this form and storing the results with Django -- if it always had the same number of textareas, it'd be easy, but I don't know how to do it with a variable number. My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
    <form action="foo" method="post" id="survey_form">
      <input type="textarea" rows="4" cols="20">
    </form>
    <button onclick="addQuestion();">add question</button>
</body>
```

The `addQuestion()` function just adds another textarea input to the form:

```
function addQuestion() {
    var form = document.getElementById('survey_form');
    var new_text_area = document.createElement('input');
    new_text_area.setAttribute('type','textarea');
    new_text_area.setAttribute('rows', '4');
    new_text_area.setAttribute('cols', '20');
    form.appendChild(new_text_area);
}
```

My Django model has a field for a list of strings; this is working properly. Now the question is how to get the form data from `request.POST` as a list. I was thinking about giving each new textarea its own unique identifier (`textarea_1`, `textarea_2`, etc.), and then looping and looking to see if `request.POST['textarea_' + str(i)]` exists, and adding it onto a list of strings. This seems *really* inefficient, though, and pretty ugly to boot. Is there a better, more Pythonic way of doing this?

Also, I'm not totally sure about how to give each textarea a unique identifier -- I'm new to JS, and all my knowledge has been gained from Google searches. I was thinking about using a closure over an index variable `i` and then incrementing `i` each time `addQuestion()` is called. Does that make sense?

And finally, a pointer to a quick hit-the-ground-running tutorial on JS for programmers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). They let you edit multiple objects in one form. Your formset would ideally be on the Question class.

From JS, you'd then add new textareas with names like `id_form-1-content`, `id_form-2-content` etc.

And [in your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates), you'd have something like:

```
formset = QuestionFormSet(request.POST)
if formset.is_valid(): 
    # etc.
```